# Xcode proper Auto Layout Constraints missing for circular profile picture across different devices

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, aspect-ratio

- I want to know what constraints should be added to make that User
  Image View stay **the same ratio** and also **probably the same
  size** across different iOS devices.
- **This is the Storyboard view of my profile image.**
  [image]
- **Below is the document outline hierarchy where Button and User Image View are put in a separate view.** (I am not sure if this is really needed or not.)
  [image]
- **Attributes Inspector of the User Image View.**
  [image]
- **Sizes Inspector of the User Image View.**
  [image]
- **This is supposed to be a circle.** 
  [image]

Comment: image view already have equal height and equal width constraints. Imageview size will remain same for all the devices.

Comment: @Bilal No, it is not. Image View size keeps changing accordingly to different devices. Could it be because of the property of the View in which Image View is?

Comment: Add some screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You should remove all the constraints and add the constraint VERTICAL SPACING, HORIZONTAL SPACING, WIDTH(Fixed), HEIGHT(Fixed). It should look like below. It will give you fixed sized ImageView on all the devices.

[image]